# What is the attribute to set the surface of solution in ansys mechanical 2020r1

Tags: ansys

I am trying to use script to set the surface in solution. I have already added the surface in construction geometry part and set the scoping method in solution to surface. I have already tried to the record function and it use Surface attribute which is a read only attribute. Which attribute do I need to use to set the surface attribute?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the surface is already created and I can store it like this (you have to adjust the index):

```
ConstructionGeometry = ExtAPI.DataModel.Project.Model.ConstructionGeometry
surf = ConstructionGeometry.Children[1]
```

I'm further assuming the result object is for example a stress result and is already created and I can store it here:

```
solution = ExtAPI.DataModel.Project.Model.Analyses[0].Solution 
result = solution.Children[4]
```

Than I can point the surface to the result object:

```
result.Surface = surf
```